# Easier way to sort through Notepad++ to look for duplicate IP addresses

Tags: logging, ip, comparison, notepad++, text-files

Please bear with me, it may sound complicated. Can clarify if needed.

I developed a interesting way to look through logs (which are saved in a text file and opened in Notepad++) by putting them in a directory. I would download the latest log file and overwrite the old ones. There are 20 text files, some over 50,000 lines.

Inside the directory, I would open one text file (let's call it log.txt) and do Find in Files (Ctrl+Shift+F). I would point it at the directory that contains all the text files and off I go.

So far, I have been doing it this way and was wondering if there was an easier way. I input a number or IP address to search in all the files and if there is a hit, I take it from there.

Is there an easier way to search a batch of characters, such as IPs, against all the text files so that it just prints me wherever those IPs are shown in the logs?

This is for a ban list.

The way I have been doing it seems fine but so slow. Would love some help on making this process more efficient and would appreciate any and all help!

Thank you!

Comment: What OS are you using? grep or similar would seem to do what you want. Any little script. Means the question is a bit broad.

Comment: Win10. Will look into grep and see how it plays out.